# How to convert total seconds value to string in 'hours minutes seconds' format

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert seconds to hours , minutes and seconds.

Example:

```
int totalseconds = 5049;
```

How do i use one message box to display the results in the form:

```
H:1 M:24 S:9
```

Comment: where did u get stuck? in division by 60?

Answer (score 8):

```
  var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5049);
    int hr = timeSpan.Hours;
    int mn = timeSpan.Minutes;
    int sec = timeSpan.Seconds;
    MessageBox.Show("H:" + hr + " M:" + mn + " S:" + sec);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
MessageBox message = new MessageBox();
int totalseconds = 5049;
int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
int minutes = (totalSeconds % 3600) / 60;
int seconds = (totalSeconds % 3600) % 60;
message.ShowDialog(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", hours, minutes, seconds));
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You can use a TimeSpan:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalsecond);

MessageBox.Show(string.Format("H: {0} M:{1} S:{2}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds));
```

Comment: You should probably use `TotalHours` instead of `Hours`, in case the number of seconds goes over 1 day.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert from seconds,

```
    var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5049);
    int hh = timeSpan.Hours;
    int mm = timeSpan.Minutes;
    int ss = timeSpan.Seconds;
    MessageBox.Show("Hours" + hh + " Minutes" + mm + " Seconds" + ss);
```